# Linq to SQL many to many relationships, working with collections

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I have a mobile application where I am trying to utilise the windows phone database.
However I have run into a little problem.

here is what I have so far.

```
[Table]
public class CollectionManager
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int FilmID { get; set; }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int CollectionID { get; set; }

    private EntityRef<FilmData> film;
    [Association(ThisKey = "FilmID", OtherKey = "ID", Storage = "film")]

    public FilmData Film{ get { return film.Entity; } set { film.Entity = value; } }

    private EntityRef<Collection> collection;
    [Association(ThisKey = "CollectionID", OtherKey = "ID", Storage = "collection")]

    public Collection Collection { get { return collection.Entity; } set { collection.Entity = value; } }
}


[Table]
public class FilmData
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int FilmID { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey = "ID", OtherKey = "FilmID")]
    public EntitySet<CollectionManager> CollectionManager { get; set; }
}


[Table]
public class Collection
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int CollectionID { get; set; }

    [Association(ThisKey = "ID", OtherKey = "CollectionID ")]
    public EntitySet<CollectionManager> CollectionManager { get; set; }
}
```

So these are my 3 tables, however I am struggling to

- Add a film to a collection
- Get all films in a collection.

Any help would me much appreciated, and thanks very much for taking the time to read this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have your `EntitySet<>` properties backwards.  You have a `FilmData` class that has many `Collection` and your `Collection` class has many `CollectionManager`.  If you want to add `FilmData` to a `Collection` then your `Collection` should have many `FilmData`.